# PHP complex while-loop logic

Tags: php, math, while-loop

I'm having a problem writing a suitable while loop logic in php, here is my code:

```
$applied_to = "Battery";            # rule applies to this product
$items      = $_GET['items'];       # how many items we have of this product
$forquan    = 3;                     # rule applies to this quantity of product
$autoadd    = "Power Inverter";  # when rule is met add this product.

if ($applied_to == "Battery"){
    print "We Have $items $applied_to<br>";
    print "The rule says we need 1 $autoadd for each 1-$forquan $applied_to<br><hr />";

    $counter = $items;
    while($counter > 0){
        if ($forquan / $items > 1){
            print "we need 1 $autoadd<br>";
        }
        $counter--;
    }
}
```

Now what i want is to add one additional product `$autoadd` if we have 1-3 Batteries, and 2 `$autoadd` if we have 3-6 and so on.

I tried so many different combinations of while loops if statements etc, but i cant seem to get the perfect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply calculate the number of required products and then iterate over that number:

```
<?php
$applied_to = "Battery";            # rule applies to this product
$items      = $_GET['items'];       # how many items we have of this product
$forquan    = 3;                    # rule applies to this quantity of product
$autoadd    = "Power Inverter";     # when rule is met add this product.

if ($applied_to == "Battery"){
    print "We Have $items $applied_to<br>\n";
    print "The rule says we need 1 $autoadd for each 1-$forquan $applied_to<br>\n<hr />\n";

    $countAddProducts = ceil($items / $forquan);
    for ($i=0; $i<$countAddProducts; $i++) {
        print "we need 1 $autoadd<br>\n";
    }
}
```

The loops output then is `n` times the string "we need 1 Power Inverter", where `n` is the rounded up value of `$items` divided by `$forquan`.

Answer (score 0):

[php5 Math function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_abs.asp)

```
<?php 

$applied_to = "Battery";            # rule applies to this product
$items      = $_GET['items'];       # how many items we have of this product
$forquan    = 3;                     # rule applies to this quantity of product
$autoadd    = "Power Inverter";  # when rule is met add this product.

if ($applied_to == "Battery"){
    print "We Have $items $applied_to<br>";
    print "The rule says we need 1 $autoadd for each 1-$forquan $applied_to<br><hr />";

    while($items > 0){
 echo abs($forquan/$items); #check abs value
        if (abs($forquan/$items) > 1){
            print "we need 1 $autoadd<br>";
        }
        $items--;
    }
}
?>
```